# Drupal 8 Webform File upload

Tags: webforms, drupal-8

I have a simple form with just a field to upload a file on a Drupal 8 site using the Webform module 6.0.1. If I test the form using webforms test tool, the file gets uploaded fine, it displays the loading icon for couple seconds and its ready to upload, but if I try the same in a page with the form embedded as a block, I can not upload the file it will always show me the following message if I try to submit the form, no matter how long I wait.

> "File upload in progress. Uploaded file may be lost. Do you want to
> continue?"

Just for testing, I increased the max upload file to 2GB and the file I'm uploading is just 5kb.
All the .js libraries I can think of are on my template.info.yml file. (core/drupal, core/jquery, core/drupal.ajax)
The private folder has been set up in my settings.php and has the permissions set correctly the .htaccess file is also set as recommended for Drupal.
I have try to upload the files in the public folder just as desperation but I get the same error

Any help will be appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is more than a year old but JIC anyone else had this problem:

There are four files where you might have to make changes to raise the memory limit on uploads. The first are two separate **php.ini** files. One is your server's php.ini and the other is the Drupal installation's php.ini in the Drupal root folder. The server's php.ini will apply the settings to all Drupal installs (and anything using PHP) on the server, while the Drupal root php.ini file will only apply to that Drupal installation. Make changes in the **php.ini** file(s) under **memory_limit**, **upload_max_filesize**, **post_max_size**. You can often edit the server's php.ini file through cPanel's MultiPHP INI Editor.

The next file is the **.htacess** file where you would change the value under **php_value memory_limit**. Changing this only affects the Drupal install the .htaccess file belongs to. This file can be found in the Drupal root directory but is sometimes hard to find because it is a hidden file. The FTP client Forklift has the option to show hidden files under View > Show View Options > Show Hidden Files. Your FTP client of choice may also have an option to show hidden files.

The last file is the **settings.php** file (sites/default/settings.php) and the value to change can be found under **ini_set('memory_limit', '')**. For example: ini_set('memory_limit', '64M'); Again, this only affects the Drupal install the settings.php file belongs to.

> **memory_limit** This sets the maximum amount of memory in bytes that a script is allowed to allocate. This helps prevent poorly written scripts for eating up all available memory on a server. Note that to have no memory limit, set this directive to -1.

> **post_max_size**  Sets max size of post data allowed. This setting also affects file upload. To upload large files, this value must be larger than upload_max_filesize. Generally speaking, memory_limit should be larger than post_max_size.

> **upload_max_filesize** The maximum size of an uploaded file.